# R: filter dataframe by pairs of neighbors?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a dataframe of neighbors, where a cell (let's say pixel) `a` neighbors cell `b, c, d`, etc. This works like a moving window, so I have a `central_id` and then `neighbors` where each `central` has unique neighbors. Then I have a dataframe with values of that cell at specific time. I need to compare what is the difference in that values between each central cell and its neighbors, and how does this vary over time?

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(3)
nbrs <- data.frame(central_id = c("a", "a", "a",
                                  "b", "b", "b", 
                                  "c", "c", "d", 
                                  "e"),
                   nbrs_id    = c("b", "c", "d",
                                  "a", "c", "e",
                                  "a", "b", "e", "d"))


# Generate data with values
df <- data.frame(year = rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 5),
                 id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 vals = 10+ rnorm(15))
```

My desired dataframe looks like this, keeping clear what are the neighbors:

```
  year central_id central_val nbrs_id nbrs_val
1    1          a   10.074955       b 8.354045
2    1          a   10.074955       c 11.774009
3    1          a   10.074955       d 10.765968
4    1 ...............
```

How to first efficiently filter value datasets to get values by id, and then create a table by putting it together?  I have around 10 millions of rows so I am looking for something efficient. Until now, I used  just some simple filtering to get the particular value like `df%>% filter(year == 1 & id == 'a')` to get my `vals` but this takes forever. I am sure there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do u want this?

```r
set.seed(3)
nbrs <- data.frame(central_id = c("a", "a", "a",
                                  "b", "b", "b", 
                                  "c", "c", "d", 
                                  "e"),
                   nbrs_id    = c("b", "c", "d",
                                  "a", "c", "e",
                                  "a", "b", "e", "d"))


# Generate data with values
df <- data.frame(year = rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 5),
                 id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 vals = 10+ rnorm(15))
library(dplyr)

df %>% left_join(nbrs, by = c('id' = 'central_id')) %>%
  left_join(df, by = c('year' = 'year', 'nbrs_id' = 'id'),
            suffix = c('', '_nbrs'))
#>    year id      vals nbrs_id vals_nbrs
#> 1     1  a  9.038067       b  9.707474
#> 2     1  a  9.038067       c 10.258788
#> 3     1  a  9.038067       d  8.847868
#> 4     1  b  9.707474       a  9.038067
#> 5     1  b  9.707474       c 10.258788
#> 6     1  b  9.707474       e 10.195783
#> 7     1  c 10.258788       a  9.038067
#> 8     1  c 10.258788       b  9.707474
#> 9     1  d  8.847868       e 10.195783
#> 10    1  e 10.195783       d  8.847868
#> 11    2  a 10.030124       b 10.085418
#> 12    2  a 10.030124       c 11.116610
#> 13    2  a 10.030124       d  8.781143
#> 14    2  b 10.085418       a 10.030124
#> 15    2  b 10.085418       c 11.116610
#> 16    2  b 10.085418       e 11.267369
#> 17    2  c 11.116610       a 10.030124
#> 18    2  c 11.116610       b 10.085418
#> 19    2  d  8.781143       e 11.267369
#> 20    2  e 11.267369       d  8.781143
#> 21    3  a  9.255218       b  8.868781
#> 22    3  a  9.255218       c  9.283642
#> 23    3  a  9.255218       d 10.252652
#> 24    3  b  8.868781       a  9.255218
#> 25    3  b  8.868781       c  9.283642
#> 26    3  b  8.868781       e 10.152046
#> 27    3  c  9.283642       a  9.255218
#> 28    3  c  9.283642       b  8.868781
#> 29    3  d 10.252652       e 10.152046
#> 30    3  e 10.152046       d 10.252652
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @thanks @AnilGoyal!! I thought there should be some simple solution, but did not figure out that it would be that simple! :-D